# Get row vector of 2d vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of vector in C++ defined with: `vector < vector<double> > A;`

Let's suppose that A has been filled with some values. Is there a quick way to extract a row vector from A ?

For instance, `A[0]` will give me the first column vector, but how can I get quicky the first row vector?

Comment: strictly speaking in your `vector<vector>>` there is no row-vector. If you want one you need to construct it. Depending on what you want you should consider to have a view rather than creating a new container

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding things but wouldn't A[0] be the first row?

Comment: @c_student its a matter of convention, swap "row" with "column" and the question is still the same

Comment: If this is supposed to be a matrix, you shouldn't use `vector<vector<double>>` (memory locality, allocations). Look at [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), it has all you need!

Comment: what did you try? why is it too slow? what to you need the row vector for? I am afraid without more context you cannot get a better answer than "create a new vector and fill it via looping over your matrix"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "quick" way with that data structure, you have to iterate each column vector and get the value for desired row and add it to temporary row vector. Wether this is fast enough for you or not depends on what you need. To make it as fast as possible, be sure to allocate right amount of space in the target row vector, so it doesn't need to be resized while you add the values to it.

Simple solution to performance problem is to use some existing matrix library, such as Eigen suggested in comments.

If you need to do this yourself (because it is assignment, or because of licensing issues, or whatever), you should probably create your own "Matrix 2D" class, and hide implementation details in it. Then depending on what exactly you need, you can employ tricks like:

- have a "cache" for rows, so if same row is fetched many times, it can be fetched from the cache and a new vector does not need to be created
- store data both as vector of row vectors, and vector of column vectors, so you can get either rows or columns at constant time, at the cost of using more memory and making changes twice as expensive due to duplication of data
- dynamically change the internal representation according to current needs, so you get the fixed memory usage, but need to pay the processing cost when you need to change the internal representation
- store data in flat vector with size of rows*columns, and calculate the correct offset in your own code from row and column

But it bears repeating: someone has already done this for you, so try to use an existing library, if you can...

Answer (score 1):

There is no really fast way to do that. <s>Also as pointed out, I would say that the convention is the other way around, meaning that `A[0]` is actually the first row, rather than the first column.</s> However even *trying* to get a column is not really trivial, since

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{0}
{0, 1, 2}
```

is a very possible `vector<vector<double>> A`, but there is no real column `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`. If you wish to enforce behavior like same length columns, creating a `Matrix` class may be a good idea (or using a library).

You could write a function that would return a `vector<double>` by iterating over the rows, storing the appropriate column value. But you would have to be careful about whether you want to copy or point to the matrix values (`vector<double>` / `vector<double *>`). This is not very fast as the values are not next to each other in memory.

Comment: I wouldn't say there is any kind of "convention" over rows and columns. That's completely arbitrary decision which is which. One way is probably more *common*, but it's not a convention to follow.

Comment: Good point. I guess I would just like to believe that my way is the way everyone  does it :D. If there is no performance aspect involved, because when I write it as a literal using `{ {} {} {} }` over multiple lines, you get that nice row-wise schema.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: in your case there is no corresponding simple option as for columns. And one of the reasons is that vector> is a particular poorly suited container for multi-dimensional data.

In multi-dimension it is one of the important design decisions: which dimension you want to access most efficiently, and based on the answer you can define your container (which might be very specialized and complex).

For example in your case: it is entirely up to you to call A[0] a 'column' or a 'row'. You only need to do it consistently (best define a small interface around which makes this explicit). But STOP, don't do that:

This brings you to the next level: for multi-dimensional data you would typically not use vector> (but this is a different issue). Look at smart and efficient solutions already existing e.g. in ublas https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html or eigen3 https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/

You will never be able to beat these highly optimized libraries.